# addition of items in a listbox

Tags: vb.net

Bellow pls find the code in VB 2008. I must sum up the numbers in the xlistscorebox

```
    Dim tot As Integer
    Dim scoresentered As Integer
    For index As Integer = 0 To Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        tot = tot + Val(Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count)
        For se As Integer = 0 To Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            scoresentered = Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count
        Next
    Next

    Me.xscoreave.Text = tot / scoresentered.ToString
    Me.xtotalscoreTextBox.Text = tot.ToString
    Me.xtotscoreentered.Text = scoresentered.ToString
```

The issue is that the calculation is giving wrong results.
Any comment will be highly appreciate.

Cecilia

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim TotalScore as Integer
For Each x As String In Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems
     TotalScore = TotalScore + Convert.ToInt32(x)
Next
dim AverageScore as Decimal = TotalScore / Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count
dim ScoresEntered = Me.xListscoreBox.SelectedItems.Count
```